# Copy script-code-snippets from a PDF file (repair line breaks)

Tags: pdf, text-formatting, evince

I'm experiencing the problem with pdf files containing `script examples`. When I manually copy the snippets the structure (line breaks) get completely messed up. As far as I understand this is because some kind of `columns` are added to the print when the PDF is compiled.

[image]
Snippet from: [The Linux Command Line (TLCL)](http://www.linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) by William Shotts (P.469 on "17.10" and P.467 on "16.07")

**If I copy this section I get a result like:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# file_info: simple file information program
PROGNAME=$(basename $0)
if [[ -e
echo
file
echo
stat
else
echo
exit
fi
$1 ]]; then
-e "\nFile Type:"
$1
-e "\nFile Status:"
$1
"$PROGNAME: usage: $PROGNAME file" >&2
```

**My Question is:** "Is there some regularity in the way this "columns/line breaks" are added so I could repair the snippet(s) with a script?"

I'm using: `Evince 3.26.0-2` as document (PDF) viewer.

Comment: I don't get this at all: when I select the text in the PDF file and middle-click in an emacs buffer, I get the script nicely indented. So it may depend on how you cut and paste and perhaps into what program you paste.

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure but I think this might also be related to how the pdf is compiled and might not be the same with every PDF file. I select the `text` with the mouse, press `ctr+c` to copy and `ctr+shift+v` to paste into `nano`

Comment: You can open the .pdf with your browser , the copy and past should work for you . Using a pdf viewer is more complicated.

Comment: @GAD3R cheers, that works :-) only indentation gets lost this way, this is not to much of a hassle. THANKS! Seems to be rather a thing of the `pdf-viewer` then? it is `evince` in my case.

Comment: A pdf editor should be helpful , AFAIk you cannot edit a pdf through evince , a pdf viewer with the edit option should be helpful .

Comment: @nath: I downloaded the book you linked to and I cut-and-pasted one of the example scripts, so the PDF should be identical to what you have.

Comment: @Nick the problem seems to be my PDF-viewer `evince`, if I view the PDF in my browser as GAD3R suggested, it looses only the `indentation` which is not too much of a problem. Maybe I need to have a look for a different PDF-viewer on my Desktop, since viewing in my browser is not a long-term solution for me. As  GAD3R recommended it should have `editing` capabilities. I'll update this in my Question later...

Comment: @nath: FWIW I use xpdf for viewing.